# Print elements of a custom linked list in ascending order

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm relatively new to Java and trying to learn on my free-time before I start taking on bigger data structures. Tonight its all about the Linked List. I have a LinkedList and trying to put the list in ascending order. Say we have numbers 5, 4, 6, 9, 1.

How would you write a method - to actually make it  1, 4, 5, 6, 9?

Right now, I'm currently trying to do this and all I'm having is:

```
public void order (LinkedList head) {
    if (head == null)
      return;
    else {
      order(head.next);
      System.out.print(" " + head.data);
      return;
```

Instead of ascending order its printing out the reverse of the original linked list: 1, 9, 6, 4, 5.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `Collections.sort(list);`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I don't think this is the JDK's `LinkedList`.

Comment: Linked List is just the class name.  I was hoping to use recursion and recursively go through it to be honest. Not take the simple way out anyway.

Comment: @shmosel Yeah, missed that.

Comment: @ohvanity How do you expect to sort a list without comparing values anywhere?

Comment: Use any of the sorting algorithms, `bubble` or `insertion` or so many to pick from.

Answer (score 3):

If `LinkedList` is a class defined by yourself, either you

1) Write your own sort method to perform sort or

2) Let your `Node` class from which forms up your `LinkedList` to implement `Comparable`. Create an `ArrayList` and add the nodes into it. After that you will be able to sort it with `Collections.sort(yourNewArrayList)`.

You will have something like:

```
public class Node implements Comparable<Node>{
    private int value;
    //constructor, getters and other members not shown

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Node n){
        return this.getValue() - n.getValue();
    }
}

ArrayList list<Node> = new ArrayList<Node>();
while(linkedList.hasNext()){
    list.add(linkedList.next());
}

Collections.sort(list);
```

It is also worth taking note that the sort implemented by Java uses Dual-Pivot Quicksort which gives you O(n(log n) performance.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices here, depending on your goals:

1. For code that works, use `java.util.LinkedList` or `java.util.ArrayList` and `java.util.Collections.sort()`. These are written by very good programmers and used all of the time by millions of programmers around the world. So you do not have to worry about bugs and can get to work on writing something useful.
2. If you are interested in learning the nuts and bolts of data structures, it appears that you have already written your own `LinkedList` class. Now you need to write your own `sort()` method. Sorting is a very well understood problem and there are many online resources available that explain different sorting algorithms. These are good learning tools because there are so many variations with different strengths and weaknesses.